# Why vim does not preserve [c] flag when g& used?

Tags: vim

Vim's `g&` is equal to `:%s//~/&`. According to documentation it

> repeat last substitute with last search pattern on all lines with the **same** flags

We can specify the `c` flag to confirm each substitution.
If we execute a substitution with `gIc` flags and we exit with `a` from `replace with xxxx (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?`, then the `c` flag is not included in the repeated substitution with `g&`.

Why? Is there any option in vim to cease this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: You are talking about "substitution", not "search".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; the behavior contradicts the documentation. The implementation implements the `a(ll)` answer by clearing the (`static`, and therefore persistent) `do_ask` flag. In the source code, this is in `ex_cmds.c`, function `do_sub()`:

```
        if (typed == 'a')
        {
            do_ask = FALSE;
            break;
        }
```

In fact, there's a similar issue with the `l(ast)` answer: this one clears `do_all`, and thereby "forgets" a `g(lobal)` flag on repetition.

This affects both `g&` as well as the `:&&` command.

**Edit**: Bug [reported to vim_dev](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/50525).

Comment: Then this is probably a bug, right? I am considering on posting a bug report.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing so; will update my answer with a link soon.